# Debugging Protractor in Vs 2013

Tags: angularjs, debugging, visual-studio-2013, protractor

I followed the instructions here:[Visual Studio 2013 protractor intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28748967/visual-studio-2013-protractor-intellisense)

Everything worked fine, then I rebooted, and now whenever it try to debug, the 
breakpoint turns white and it says no symbols are loaded.

In c# I'd look a windows->Debug->Modules, but it opens and closes too fast.
I tried adding debug to the parameters for the node exe (protractor.com)
but no joy.

Any ideas what is needed to get the symbols loading again?

I loaded Chutzpah  about the time I rebooted, so I uninstalled that, but no joy. Maybe Chutzpah changed some settings in VS that I need to restore?

Is there any other way to get legit full on debugging in Protractor tests, I mean step in lines of code, set watches, examine variables, all visually,  not that debugging on the command line stuff it does naturally..